# Better name for "non-negative" value?

Tags: validation, language-agnostic, numbers

I'm validating that the integer is zero or greater.  To describe the requirement as "zero or greater" feels too verbose.  To say "non-negative" introduces negative language, which I try to avoid when I can.

What concise descriptor do you use when describing a value that must be zero or greater?

Comment: Why avoid negative language?  Often the most precise way to describe something is to describe what set it *doesn't* belong to.

Comment: @Kirk Woll: My best answer to that is "because there's something better".  If, in fact, all of these smart people cannot provide something "better", then "non-negative" may be what I use.

Comment: "zero or greater" is not **that** verbose

Comment: @NimChimpsky: Agreed, really.  I guess I was just hoping to be even more concise.

Comment: If you want something that rolls off the tongue, you might try "nought'n'up". In fact, the majority of names at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_for_the_number_0_in_English sound fantastic when appended with "'n'up" :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would argue that the answer depends on what audience you are writing for.  If this is for other developers (i.e. for variable naming or API docs), then I think "non-negative" would most precisely express what you want.  If this is for end-user documentation, then "positive" will be fine.

Always consider your audience, even while programming.

Comment: It definitely depends on the audience, which isn't clearly stated in the question. Mathamatitions: "whole number" or "natural number", programmers: "non-negative 32-bit signed integer", others: "positive number or zero".

Comment: This is a great answer, especially the last sentence.  There are lots of great answers, and I'm sure they'll all continue to get upvoted as folks find each appropriate for their audience.

Answer (score 7):

`positiveValue` or `unsignedValue`

If you're using `unsignedValue` as a name, you should also make sure you use the matching unsigned data type (if your language supports it). If you use the proper data type, you wouldn't have to validate anything...the type would do it for you.

Comment: unsigned is quite c++ like, and i like it too ;]

Comment: Good suggestions.  "Positive" may or may not include zero (depending on whom you ask), so I don't like the confusion there.  "Unsigned" narrows my audience too much.  I'd like this name to be consumable by non-programmers/etc types.

Comment: unsigned is just as negative as nonnegative

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I sounds like the @lance is trying to develop language which will be presented to a user... in which I don't think something like "Total cost must be an unsignedValue" would go over very well.  Also, zero is neither positive nor negative so positiveValue is certainly no good.

Comment: I did, actually, fail to specify my audience, but @Stephen Swensen is correct.  This is language the end user will see.  I'm really enjoying the answers which don't assume that, though, as this problem will apply to more audiences in time.

Answer (score 6):

Stick with **non-negative**. The meaning
is clear, and more importantly, correct.

By analogy, consider the name given to
a list of things sorted in ascending order. Calling the list *ascending*
is only correct if you explicitly exclude the possibility of having
repeated values. If the list contains two or more items of the same value it cannot
be called *ascending* because 
two things that are equal cannot be placed in ascending order with respect to 
each other. In fact, such a list is properly called *non-descending*.

The negative/zero/positive problem falls into the same sort of trap. There are 3 categories of 
number: Negative, zero and positive. Describing a set that
includes any two of the categories can be done by naming the two or by negating
the possibility of the third. Any other type of description would be ambiguous.

Comment: This is the first time I've heard the term non-descending.  A Google search reveals much ado about testicles.

Comment: I don't think having duplicate values violates the concept of ascending (or descending) order.  Given the values [1, 3, 6, 6, 7], subsequent values change by [2, 3, 0, 1].  The moment of change at index 3 is indeterminate (from this one sample, it's impossible to determine if the list is sorted ascending, descending, or not at all), but the overall order is unequivocally ascending.  You could better say that the sublist [6, 6] is both in ascending and descending order, rather than neither, defining that ascending order is a non-negative change, instead of only positive change.

Comment: @P Daddy: Ascending means increasing order. The definition of increasing implies a non-zero positive difference between elements E[N] and E[N+1] where N varies from 1 to the list size less 1. If any of these differences is zero, the best you can claim is that the list is in non-descending order because any other claim would violate the definition of ascending. Claiming ascending order in the face of duplicate values is not an uncommon and often harmless mistake. Some people consider such a claim good enough for most "government work".

Comment: Nowhere can I find such a definition of ascending or descending order to back up your statements.  I truly understand your viewpoint, as you've defined ascending by strict analogy with positive numbers, and applied this analogy to every delta within the list of ordered items.  In reality, however, the 0 delta between duplicate items does not disrupt the overall order of the list.  For instance this line undeniably ascends: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+0,+1,+2,+2,+3,+4

Comment: @P Daddy: Try searching for the term "nondecreasing" it may be more appropriate. I based my answer on a paragraph from Knuths: The Art of Computer Programming; volume 3 - Searching and Sorting. To paraphrase Knuth: The goal of sorting is to determine a permutation of the records where the keys are in nondecreasing order. On first reading it took me some time to realize the significance of those words. Also, have a look at this [definition of nondecreasing](http://everything2.com/title/nondecreasing). In retrospect, I probably should have said nodecreasing as opposed to non-descending.

Comment: FWIW, mathematicians call a function or series "monotonically increasing" if it never decreases, and "strictly monotonically increasing" if it only increases.

Answer (score 4):

[natural numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number) or simply natural

Comment: Natural numbers are all integers. If fractional values are allowed, natural numbers won't work.

Comment: Depending on who you ask, natural numbers may or may not include 0.

Comment: Note that the question states the value is (understood to be) an integer.

Comment: @Thomas Lötzer: To be sure. The referenced wikipedia page begins with: "(sometimes zero is also included)".  That's not the clarity I'm seeking.

Comment: I've seen it done differently, too. E.g. `N` for non-negative, and `N \ { 0 }` for positive, or `N` for positive and `No` for non-negative, Usually introduced explicitely as "convention for this course".

Comment: yes, `Z*` could be the answer, which is called "nonnegative integers", but is excluded by the OP so I think `N` is the closest

Answer (score 3):

I'd stick with non-negative. If it's good for maths, it must be good for users ;)

However, if the label is just "Number of X", this additional information isn't really necessary, and a validation result can have negative wording (e.g. "negative values are not allowed").

Comment: "If it's good for maths, it must be good for users." -- haha!

Answer (score 1):

I would stick with simply Positive. Althought it's not strictly right, most people won't be surprised ou tricked by this naming.

Unsigned is a good choice to, as it is widely associated with positive number in programming languages (Ok, with number only positive or negative. But you get the idea)

Comment: "most people [will consider zero included in 'positive']" -- My experiences suggest this might not be so safe an assumption?  I've encountered a lot of confusion (in math, in UIs, in lots of places) about whether or not zero is valid when asked for a positive value.

Answer (score 1):

**Positive**

And greater zero for exclusive meaning

---

Note that unsigned integers are naturals ;)

Answer (score 1):

For validation messages, I normally go for something like:

> "The number of widgets cannot be negative"

rather than:

> "The number of widgets has to be zero or more"

Answer (score 1):

Unsigned Integer

Answer (score 0):

For a requirements document, I would prefer "zero or greater".   Requirements document will be (hopefully) widely read by people including those with a non-technical and a non-mathematics background.  The phrase "zero or greater" makes it the border case clear (ie, zero is allowed).  "Non-negative" may not be as clear to everyone.

Answer (score -2):

Unsigned would be incorrect, as that refers to a variable that can **only** be positive.
I believe positive would be the correct name for this.

Comment: what does an unsigned negative number look like ?

Comment: @NimChipmsky: actually, it can only be positive, but people can do x -unsignedSomething, and use it as an only negative.